# phusion passenger start fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, passenger

When I try:

```
passenger start -p 3003
```

**I got the error:**

> You cannot specify both --address/--port and --socket. Please choose
>   either one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I found that there was a new file

`Passengerfile.json`

which I didn't create at all. Removed the file, passenger work fine again.

I guess the question, now, is how was that file created?

Comment: if it works then check-mark this answer; and I am deleting my soln

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
passenger start -a 0.0.0.0 -p 3003 -d
```

***P.S.*** `-a` option tells the server to listen on all IP addresses. If you remove it, you will only be able to access it from localhost

***Pro Tip:*** If this does not work. Try again after re-starting your computer ;)

Comment: Tried this but no luck. Passengerfile.json file was the issue in my case.

Answer (score 0):

you can also try this

```
passenger start -a 0.0.0.0 -p 3003
```

or

```
passenger start -a 0.0.0.0 -p 3003 -d -e production
```

in case of any confusion you can ask help

```
passenger start --help
```

Comment: Tried this but no luck. Passengerfile.json file was the issue in my case.